# Unable to find mongod.conf file in ubuntu

Tags: mongodb

I want to change **auth=false** to **auth=true** in mongod.conf file in ubuntu but not able to find mongod.conf file in /etc/. So which are the other possible locations for finding this file.

Answer (score 15):

Finding your mongod config path using mongo shell:

```
db.adminCommand('getCmdLineOpts');
```

It returns all command line options. Just for config path:

```
db.adminCommand('getCmdLineOpts').parsed.config;
```

Reference: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/getCmdLineOpts/

--

You can create manually. Path: `/etc/mongod.conf`

Also take a look https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/configuration-options/#use-the-configuration-file

Comment: Thank you sir for you reply.
Actually I am new to mongodb and ubuntu. And working on server which was configured by other person so there must be any mongod.confg file on the server form where mongdb server is taking its current configuration and i just want to edit that file only. so is there any other possible location for finding this file?

Comment: Also take a look here: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/getCmdLineOpts/ You can find your config file.

Comment: thanks but getting errmsg: not authorized on admin to execute command

Comment: enter "use admin" first

Answer (score 8):

In my case Ubuntu 18.04: `/etc/mongodb.conf`

Answer (score 5):

Still got this in 2020.
reinstalling all mongodb-related packages solved it for me

```
apt purge mongo*
apt install mongodb
```

Note that simply reinstalling just mongodb package doesn't fix it.

Answer (score 1):

In a terminal run `sudo find / -name mongodb.conf` (I'm aware that the OP looks for `mongod.conf`, not sure if this is a typo? No such file on my system...)

Comment: That's confusing - mongodb official docs also say it should be `mongod.conf`, when it's actually `mongodb.conf`. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/